# Switch from student visa tier 4 to youth mobility

Tags: united-kingdom, student-visa

Is it possible to move from study visa for 3 years under tier 4 to to youth mobility if in the Commonwealth?

I should explain: I'm currently studying for 3 years in the UK following which I plan to switch to the youth mobility visa can I switch my visas in the country or do I have to leave?

Comment: You should also note that the youth mobility visa has nothing to do with the commonwealth. You should check whether your nationality is eligible.

Answer (score 3):

It does not look like you can change the visa from Tier 4 to Tier 5 while in the UK. I am basing this statement on a University website, not an official government website. Cambridge has [this web site](https://www.internationalstudents.cam.ac.uk/immigration/work-visas-after-study) which states:

> Can I switch from Tier 4 inside the UK [to a Tier 5 Youth Mobility
>   Visa]? No.